# Plone API remove_user from group does not seem to work

Tags: plone

I am trying to remove all users from a group using the Plone.Api method (within Plone4).
So I wrote this code:

```
users = api.user.get_users(groupname="The Test Group")
for user in users:
    api.group.remove_user(groupname="The Test Group", username=user.id)
```

But the api.group.remove_user call does not seem to function. What is the proper way to remove users from a group within plone?

I paused this within my `ipdb`
This are the results from my calls:

```
ipdb> api.group.get(groupname=group_name)
<GroupData at /Plone/portal_groupdata/groupname:61fbc50d623142d7887384d70f25358b used for     /Plone/acl_users/source_groups>
```

So far so good, I store this in a variable so I can try this again later (for the group argument).

```
ipdb> grp = api.group.get(groupname=group_name)
ipdb> api.user.get_users(groupname=group_name)
[<MemberData at /Plone/portal_memberdata/stolas@domain.org used for /Plone/acl_users>]
```

I notice I get my user from the group. Thus I am really in this group.

```
ipdb> user.id
'stolas@domain.org'
ipdb> api.group.remove_user(group=grp, username=user.id)
```

I try the remove call again, and check if my member is still within the group.

```
ipdb> api.user.get_users(groupname=group_name)
[<MemberData at /Plone/portal_memberdata/stolas@domain.org used for /Plone/acl_users>]
```

I still am.. 
Should I reindex security or something like that?

ps.

I also gave `with api.env.adopt_roles(['Manager'])` a try and the `getToolByName(getSite(), 'portal_groups')`
method `portal_groups.removePrincipalFromGroup` everthing rendered to a false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I could not delete it as a user I thought of the following:

```
    with api.env.adopt_roles(['Manager']):
        api.user.delete(user=self.context)
        parent = self.context.getParentNode()
        parent.manage_delObjects([self.context.getId()])
```

As the user delete might fail I deleted the object as a Manager. This seemd to work without a Hitch.

Comment: Well this seems a workflow issue. Your current user is no allowed to delete.

Answer (score 1):

plone.api uses the group tool to remove group memberships:

```python
portal_groups = portal.get_tool('portal_groups')
portal_groups.removePrincipalFromGroup(user_id, group_id)
```

I guess your `api.user.get_users(groupname="The Test Group")` call returns an empty set. 
Since you should pass the group name (group ID). Now you pass the group title.

The `api.group.remove_user` would also accept a group object instead of the group name.

```
Arguments ``groupname`` and ``group`` are mutually exclusive. You can
either set one or the other, but not both.
```

Comment: The get_users group is not empty. The name I send is really the id, 100% tested and sure. Maybe I should try parsing the group object.

Comment: Can you try with an id without spaces?

Comment: See the edit within the question for my attempts. The id does not have spaces.

Comment: Hmmm... But you are abel to remove the group membership thru the ZMI, or Plone config panel?

Comment: Odd even as an admin I can't seem to click the checkbox to select the group in the group removal location.

Comment: Well that's looks strange. I guess we need more Informations about your setup. Which Plone version exactly? Do you have any Addons installed?

Comment: Plone 4.3.2, the collective.workspace addon is installed. For the others, I doubt they trigger anything within the member system. But I'll figure this out asap.

Comment: Any progress? Did you find a solution?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to update this, I'll post the solution as the answer.